# Wie kann man gleichzeitig höflich (andere positive Eigenschaften) und direkt sein?

Tags: politeness

Meiner Meinung nach sind die Deutschen direkt und klar. Das mag ich, weil es weniger Zeit braucht etwas zu sagen. Dann ist es effizient. Deshalb versuche ich direkt zu sein, wenn ich Deutsch spreche (z.B. beim Vorstellungsgespräch), aber manchmal geht das nicht so gut, weil ich gleichzeitig auch höflich sein muss. Aber wenn ich höflich bin, dann spreche ich viel zu lang (lange Sätze mit Konjunktiv zwei).

Wie kann ich das ausgleichen? Gibt es gute Ideen?

Zum Beispiel eine Situation im Vorstellungsgespräch:

- F1 - "Brauchen Sie noch Wasser?"
- A1 - "Nein".
- A1 (höflich) - "Nein, vielen Dank. Ich bin nicht durstig."
- F2 - "Haben sie Erfahrungen in diesem Bereich?"
- A2- "Nein. Leider nicht"
- A2 (höflich und motiviert) - "Im Moment nicht. Aber, ich möchte über diesen Bereich im neuen Job lernen..."

Wenn ich etwas weniger direkt bin, wird mein Satz länger.

Comment: Ich sage über Höflichkeit oft, wir sind hier nicht bei Hofe. Das macvt selbst für mich wenig Sinn. Nun frage ich mich, ob es eher mit Hoffnung zu tun hätte. Die Erwähnung des Konjuntiv II passt dazu wunderbar. "Direkte Sprache" würde ich eher mit "dirigieren" und "Direktor" vergleichen. Die Schnittmenge aus *höflich* und *direkt* im herkömmlichen Sinne wäre "ehrlich", soweit kein absoluter Gegensatz besteht. So gesehen ist "... a-aber ich ..." eher ausweichend. Es ist ehrbar, Ziele zu haben, doch es wäre eher im Sinne der Frage, die Kenntnis der nötigen Vorraussetzungen vorzuweisen.

Comment: Die Frage ist zu allgemein und das Beispiel dafür zu speziel. Darauf kann man keine direkte Antwort geben. Höflichkeit gebraucht meist Floskeln, die stark kontext-abhängig sind, und Protokoll. Was an A1 indirekt sein soll, erschließt sich mir nicht. Problematisch empfinde ich das verbesserungswürdige Deutsch. *verbesserungswürdig* wäre übrigens eine solche Floskel. Diese ist positiv formuliert. *fehlerhaft* wäre dagegen destruktiv.

Comment: Höflichkeit und Direktheit sind für mich keine Gegenpole. Wenn man überhaupt nicht direkt ist, sondern endlos in Floskeln schwafelt, ist das nach meinem Empfinden sogar recht unhöflich.

Comment: Achtung! Ich empfinde "Ich bin nicht durstig" hier als unangemessen und darum auch nicht als gelungen höflich. Höflich wäre zum Beispiel: "Nein, danke, aber sehr freundlich von Ihnen." - Unhöflich-unpassend ist in meinem Empfinden, dass überhaupt so grobe körperliche Bedürfnisse wie "Durst" direkt erwähnt werden. Eben dies sollte man umschiffen.

Answer (score 3):

Die wichtigste Regel der deutschen Höflichkeit ist es, anderen Menschen nicht die Zeit zu stehlen. Daher sollte man gleich zu Anfang klar machen, was man meint. Es kommt also nicht darauf an, sich möglichst kurz auszudrücken, sondern möglichst klar. Das spart unnötige Gespräche, die sowieso zu nichts führen.

In einem Restaurant zahlt man für die Bedienung. Deshalb kann man praktisch ewig mit dem Kellner quatschen, um den richtigen Wein auszuwählen – der ist nämlich teuer genug, um das zu rechtfertigen. Man sollte allerdings nicht dieselbe Zeit für die Wahl zwischen Tomaten- und Zwiebelsuppe aufwenden, das könnte den Kellner schon arg nerven.

[Manchmal geht es schief.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQE44zaB4R4)

([Allerdings hat Herr Blümel in der Benimmschule trotz Bemühens eher versagt.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A5WPsT9XKnE))

Comment: Link 2 ist unrettbar kaputt - soll es vielleicht keiner sein? Dass es hier als höflich gilt, anderen nicht die Zeit zu stehlen, mag ja sein, dass es aber gleich die wichtigste Regel der dt. Höflichkeit ist scheint mir doch ein wenig weit aus dem Fenster gelehnt. Wie hat man das festgestellt?

Comment: In der Tat, der Link "http://Allerdings%20hat%20Herr%20BlC3%BCmel%20in%20der%20Benimmschule%20trotz%20Bem%C3%BChens%20eher%20versagt." ist nicht zu retten (hab's versucht...)

Comment: könnte am Fehlen einer top-level-domain liegen...

Comment: Ich hab den Link repariert.

Comment: *Pünklichkeit ist die Höflichkeit der Könige,* meinte ein bekannter (und bekennender) **Franzose**. Komisch, eigentlich.

Answer (score 3):

Man kann es nur begrenzt, wenn man bei der Wahrheit bleiben will. Am Hofe, wo die Höflichkeit herstammt, hatte man viel Zeit und Freude an ausgefallenen Ritualen.

Also muss man Kompromisse eingehen und Prioritäten setzen. Bei der Bewerbung auf eine Stelle in einem 5-Sterne-Hotel gelten sicher andere Kriterien, als bei der Bewerbung als ungelernte Hilfskraft auf dem Bau.

- F1 - "Brauchen Sie noch Wasser?"
- A1 - "Nein".
- A1 (höflich) - "Nein, vielen Dank. Ich bin nicht durstig."

"Nein, danke." sollte genügen. Es signalisiert Aufmerksamkeit für kleine Dinge, also dass man den guten Willen, den das Angebot darstellt, wahrgenommen hat und zu schätzen weiß, aber auch kein Aufhebens darum macht. Das "danke" dauert vielleicht eine viertel Sekunde - nichts, worüber man sich Sorgen machen sollte.

- F2 - "Haben sie Erfahrungen in diesem Bereich?"
- A2- "Nein. Leider nicht"
- A2 (höflich und motiviert) - "Im Moment nicht. Aber, ich möchte über diesen Bereich im neuen Job lernen..."

Statt "im Moment nicht" wäre "bisher nicht" besser. Im Moment sitzt man ja da beim Vorstellungsgespräch. Und Erfahrungen verschwinden auch nicht von eben auf gleich. In Vorstellungsgesprächen wird auch erwartet, dass man höflich ist, dass man versucht sich in einem guten Licht darzustellen, dass man Lücken beschönigt. Je nachdem, wie ernst einem der Wunsch ist, etwas dazuzulernen, wird man es konkretisieren und unterfüttern können, was der Selbstdarstellung Glaubwürdigkeit verleiht.

"Bisher nicht. Aber Blockchains sind ja so omnipräsent - ich würde mich freuen das hier lernen zu dürfen."

Oder:

"Bisher nicht. Aber ich habe eine schnelle Auffassungsgabe und arbeite mich schnell in neue Themen ein. Zuletzt habe ich Fast-Fourier-Transformationen bei der X-UP-Company gelernt, obwohl ich bei Matrizenrechnung in der Schule ziemlich mau war. Als die praktische Anwendung klar war, war es für mich ein Klacks das zu lernen."

Dass man bei einem Vorstellungsgespräch aufgeregt sein kann und vielleicht zu viel redet, kann passieren. Man sollte ein Auge auf die Gesprächspartner haben und merken, wenn man sie mit Phrasen langweilt oder ob zu kurz angebundene Antworten als unangebracht empfunden werden.

Comment: Stimmt, Cut'n'Paste-Unkultur. Korrigiert.

Answer (score 0):

Oft hilft es bei solchen Fragen, die Aussage zu zerlegen:

- F1 - "Brauchen Sie noch Wasser?"
- A1 - *Ich bin nicht durstig, brauche also kein Wasser* + *Vielen Dank, ich weiß Ihre Aufmerksamkeit zu schätzen*
- F2 - "Haben sie Erfahrungen in diesem Bereich?"
- A2 - *Ich habe keine Erfahrungen in diesem Bereich* + *Ich denke, ich wäre geeignet für diesen Bereich* + *Wenn Sie mich bezahlen, schaue ich mich da mal um!*

Der erste Teil ist bei A1 und A2 meist die "eigentliche" direkte Antwort. Das, was danach kommt, wechselt hier auf die Beziehungsebene (A1) oder versucht, das Gespräch in die richtige Richtung zu leiten (A2). Die weiteren Teile sollten also nicht nur als Höflichkeit betrachtet werden, sie haben auch einen klaren Zweck.

Wenn die Bestandteile klar sind, kann man die Aussagen einzeln komprimieren:

- F1 - "Brauchen Sie noch Wasser?"
- A1 - *Ich bin nicht durstig, brauche also kein Wasser* + *Vielen Dank, ich weiß Ihre Aufmerksamkeit zu schätzen*
- A1 - Nein, dankeschön!
- F2 - "Haben sie Erfahrungen in diesem Bereich?"
- A2 - *Ich habe keine Erfahrungen in diesem Bereich* + *Ich denke, ich wäre geeignet für diesen Bereich* + *Wenn Sie mich bezahlen, schaue ich mich da mal um!*
- A2 - "**Noch** nicht!"

Nachdem sich die Frage explizit auf ein Vorstellungsgespräch bezieht: Hier ist nicht nur die *Höflichkeit* wichtig, sondern auch die *Freundlichkeit*.